# c++ how to create 2d vector in heap?

Tags: c++11, vector, heap-memory

I know  I can create 2d vector in the stack for

```
 vector<vector<int>> dp(10,vector<int>(10,0));
```

But the question is, how do I create that in heap?

can I do something like?

```
vector<vector<int>> dp(10,vector<int>(10,0)) = new vector<vector<int>>(10,vector<int>(10,0));
```

Comment: jlu999 Is there anything you want me to add to the answer or is everything clear now?

Comment: Its clear, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The actual `vector` data will be on the heap (if there's a heap) in the first case too. It's only the ~24 bytes a `vector` occupies that will be placed on the stack (if there's a stack).

> can I do something like?

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> dp(10,vector<int>(10,0)) =
    new vector<vector<int>>(10,vector<int>(10,0));
```

No, the proper way would to store the pointer returned by `new` in a pointer:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>>* dp = new vector<vector<int>>(10,vector<int>(10,0));
```

or better, use a smart pointer:

```cpp
#include <memory>
auto dp = std::make_unique<vector<vector<int>>>(10,vector<int>(10,0));
```

This is a very unusual thing to do though and you must be really short of stack space for this to solve anything.